# Sun T2000 Solaris 10 Watchdog

Tags: sun, solaris-10, watchdog

Any ideas where the watchdog properties/settings are located on a T2000 running SPARC Solaris 10?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `eeprom | grep watchdog`.  Also look at `error-reset-recovery` I think that may have replaced watchdog it's a long time since I worked with that kit sorry.